# How can water mist lower a room's temperature?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, thermodynamics, heat-transfer

Let me start off by saying that this is strictly NOT a homework question, so before you mark it as "homework", think.

I was looking at how the water cools my body when it evaporates off it. Then I thought the specific heat capacity could be used to calculate how much energy (i.e heat) would be taken out of a room when water that absorbed it's heat is transferred out of the room.

I tried and researched all I could, but as I am not an physicist, I can't really get calculations together. Every time, I put down calculations using specific heat capacity, mass, temperature change, energy taken in/out, and then everything looks out of place.

I have a setup with one mister, which is simply a device that atomizes water to small drops (I have no clue how small), and a large fan (it draws air) on the ceiling to "suck" up the vapour and transfer it to the open.

Room size = 2m x 2m x 3m

Mister sprays 1L of water per minute (16.67ml per second), as tiny drops.

Temperature outside = 40 Celsius

I am getting confused, as some water would probably vaporise and some would remain water. I think that the small drops have a large surface area, so absorb energy fast, and thus turn into gas (steam?). I can't understand how to calculate the heat energy transfer from the room to the water and steam, how to use ratios. All this is getting messed up the more I think of it.

Can someone direct me WHAT I must calculate, as I'm really dumbfounded as of now. Please, no closing the question for God's sake. I asked in multiple SE forums, but all were closed. Is this how useful SE gets?

Comment: SE always prefers direct answerable questions to direct problems one has. I *think* i know what you’re asking, but i’m not really sure. So to help you out some, you should try to rewrite your question, you should outline an exact system and thing you’re trying to calculate, and show us what worked, or what didn’t work for you, so we can answer that directly. As it stands, i feel like i need to explain thermodynamics to you. Instead of answering what heat loss you want from your vaporizer or what the inside room temperature is. Show us your math! Even if its scribbles. We don’t mind :)

Comment: (1) You're spraying in water but sucking the air out so it must be replaced by other air. What is the temperature and relative humidity (RH) of the incoming air? (2) What is the air change rate? (3) What is the significance of the outside air temperature? (4) Tip: SE supports HTML entities such as `&deg;` for the degree symbol.

Comment: @morbo Kind words! Lacks on SE these days. I'll do as you said as soon as possible.

Comment: @Transistor I'll update the question as soon as possible.

Comment: It appears you are trying to make a DIY evaporative air conditioner for one room. If you live in a humid environment it's not going to work because you're adding more water vapor into air that already contains a lot a water vapor. Such coolers are better suited to drier air environments.

Answer (score 2):

The answer to your question is explicitly furnished in a cooling effectiveness chart contained in the *Trane Handbook Of Air Conditioning*, in the chapter dealing with *evaporative cooling*. This chart has a complex family of curves in it and axis scales on it which will yield the temperature depression (cooling effect) as a function of the ratio of water to air flow rate, water source temperature, outside air temperature, and relative humidity.

No calculations are required. You just select the input parameters, follow the lines, and their intersection point on the chart gives you the answer.

Comment: This is a really good answer. But I believe there should be some way to calculate this?

Comment: There is (this is a standard exam problem in the HVAC field of mechanical engineering), but in the chart, all the calculations have already been performed in advance, for your shopping convenience. I studied your same problem for several years myself and couldn't find out exactly how to do the calculations either, but as soon as I got a copy of that book, I had all the answers I needed!